# ViewModel's application is null when val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as SomeApplication)

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, android-viewmodel

```
companion object{
        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory{
            initializer {
                // This is the error my application
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as AmphibiansInfoApplication)
                val amphibiansInfoRepository = application.container.amphibiansInfoRepository
                AmphibiansViewModel(amphibiansInfoRepository = amphibiansInfoRepository)
            }
        }
    }
```

In this error, a **`NullPointerException`** is thrown because the code tries to cast a **`null`** value to a non-null type **`AmphibiansInfoApplication`**. Specifically, the error occurs in the **`invoke`** function of a lambda expression on line 43 of the **`AmphibiansViewModel`** class.

Here is the [Repository](https://github.com/shankarlohar/Amphibians) for application.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.shankarlohar.amphibians, PID: 22708
                                                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.shankarlohar.amphibians.AmphibiansInfoApplication
                                                                                                        at com.shankarlohar.amphibians.ui.view.AmphibiansViewModel$Companion$Factory$1$1.invoke(AmphibiansViewModel.kt:44)
                                                                                                        at com.shankarlohar.amphibians.ui.view.AmphibiansViewModel$Companion$Factory$1$1.invoke(AmphibiansViewModel.kt:42)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.InitializerViewModelFactory.create(InitializerViewModelFactory.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:156)
                                                                                                        at com.shankarlohar.amphibians.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at com.shankarlohar.amphibians.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:15)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme_androidKt.PlatformMaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.android.kt:23)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:82)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material.TextKt.ProvideTextStyle(Text.kt:265)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:81)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt$MaterialTheme$1.invoke(MaterialTheme.kt:80)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.material.MaterialThemeKt.MaterialTheme(MaterialTheme.kt:72)
                                                                                                        at com.shankarlohar.amphibians.ui.theme.ThemeKt.AmphibiansTheme(Theme.kt:38)
                                                                                                        at com.shankarlohar.amphibians.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:15)
                                                                                                        at com.shankarlohar.amphibians.ComposableSingletons$MainActivityKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:14)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:402)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:248)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:247)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:177)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:122)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
2023-05-06 15:43:03.013 22708-22708 AndroidRuntime          com.shankarlohar.amphibians          E      at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:157)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:156)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.invokeComposable(ActualJvm.jvm.kt:74)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3193)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3183)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:252)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3183)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3119)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:584)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:811)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:140)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1015)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:182)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:138)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:131)
                                                                                                        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1102)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21290)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3491)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3498)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2820)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2328)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9087)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1231)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:832)
2023-05-06 15:43:03.013 22708-22708 AndroidRuntime          com.shankarlohar.amphibians          E      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

The error message suggests that the value being cast to **`AmphibiansInfoApplication`** is **`null`**. This could happen if the value is not initialized properly or if there is a mistake in the code that retrieves the value.

Answer (score -1):

just update dependency versions in your build.gradle to the latest

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34663870)